# Django synchronous task queue to external system

Tags: python, django

I have Django application as a load balancer. It receives tasks and forwards them to available server. All communications handled as HTTP requests, i.e. django posts http request to external server and ext. server posts http request to django upon task completion. Unfortunately there's no way to check whether the ext. server is busy or not, so I need to wait for notification.

As Django process requests asynchronously I need to build some synchronous task queue which will monitor free tasks and free servers and send tasks to all available servers and then will wait until any of them reports back. I tried using celery but not sure how to "wait" for server to report back.

Comment: Have you got synchronous and asynchronous mixed up here? Django processes requests synchronously, but a task queue is asynchronous.

Comment: I think you have to remember the toral number of "open" requests per server. "open" means request send but not answered yet. If you receive an answer you reduce this total number for that particular server. If you specify a maximum per server for that number you can check if a server is busy or not

Comment: My external server responses with status 200 immediately after receiving task and then processes it :( So it sends back http request about finishing task, but two servers could finish at the same time, this way Django processes this request in parallel which leads to one task sent to two servers.